# How to cast GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#

I have:

```cs
public class TreeNode
{
    public List<TreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

and

```cs
public class Capability : TreeNode
{
}
```

Then I would like to create:

```cs
public class CapabilityList : IEnumerable<Capability>
{
    private TreeNode _capabilities = new TreeNode();

    public IEnumerator<Capability> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _capabilities.ChildNodes.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But how do I implement the GetEnumerator function above correctly?

The problem is that _capabilities.ChildNodes is `List<TreeNode>` and not `List<Capability>`. In my case, the list will only contain items of type Capability.

Comment: can you please show what `_capabilities` is and how it is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the nodes are *all* actually `Capability`, then:

```
return _capabilities.ChildNodes.Cast<Capability>().GetEnumerator();
```

If the nodes are *not all* actually `Capability`, and you want to filter to those ones, then:

```
return _capabilities.ChildNodes.OfType<Capability>().GetEnumerator();
```

(making sure that you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code file)